Free and preferably open source software for customization of the Windows taskbar
I want to have more control over the taskbar and the taskbar menu, such as changing layout styles, transparency, center the icons, etc. I would like it to be free and preferably open source.
I have tried Start11 however it is paid and I'm having consistent bugs, such as the taskbar flashing and disappearing for 1 or 2 seconds so I won't keep it.

https://windhawk.net/ maybe. It seems that your OS is Windows 11. I can't test it on Windows 11.
